# Is there a current multiplier circuit?

Tags: current

Is there an electrical circuit that can be used to multiply the current?
If yes, what is it called and how do I make it (circuit diagram)?

I have single input, so a collector emitter circuit won't help. Input is 300 mA and I want to get 1200 mA as output.

Comment: If you're looking for a current amplifier, search for common collector amplifier circuits.

Comment: There are several ways to multiply current depending on the context.  What current are you trying to multiply, by which I don't mean how many amps but where is this current flowing?

Comment: I have single input so collector emitter circuit wont help. Input is 300 milliamps and I wanna get 1200 milliapms as output.

Comment: There are plenty of voltage controlled current sources on the net so take a google look. To convert current input to voltage, use a resistor as per ohms law.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to scale the current by a factor of 4. In that case, the simplest solution is a current mirror with appropriate emitter resistors' ratio.

Comment: `I have single input, so a collector emitter circuit won't help`,Dont know what that meant,Current multiplier can be obtained using external bias V-I converter,for that you will need exteral PS,some examples are Darlington Pairs and many other,If you are in Power electronics domain,then the current can be stepped up using a transformer,you can also use step up chopper.

Comment: Are you saying you have a current source, and want to make another current source with 4 times the current? Or are you saying you have a load whose current you can measure, and want to produce 4 times the current in another load of the same impedance? Or are you saying you produce a certain current in a known load and want to quadruple the current IN THE SAME LOAD? Please explain exactly what you want.

Comment: I need a circuit to which i will give 400 milliamps as input and would want to get 1200 milliapms as output @WhatRoughBeast
got it?

Comment: Both my input and output are DC so i can't use a transformer. I will take a look at darlington pairs. Thanks @MaMba

Comment: @RochePeriyanayagam - If you want me, or anyone else, to get it, you need to answer the question.

Comment: You need more detail bro? i dont understand what more you need?

Comment: Unclear what the input and output DC voltage requirements are for this question. Energy is always conserved, so sourcing 1200mA x 1V from an input of only 300mA x 1V is not possible without passive components. Answer is highly dependent on knowing the full requirements (Vin min, Iin max, Vout min/max, Iout min/max).

Comment: OK, It's pretty clear that you want a box that when 400 milliamperes is pushed into one end of it  it'll push 1200 milliamperes into whatever's connected  to the other end of it. What's not at all clear is what's on the output side of the box.  Can you clear that up for us please?  Also, it would be nice to know what would happen on the output if we pushed 100 milliamperes into the box. Probably most important of all though, is over what range of resistances connected to the output side of the box would you have that 1200 milliamperes stay 1200 milliamperes.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying two input signals is a nonlinear operation, therefore the resulting circuit will be required to employ nonlinear components (mainly transistors of course) in appropriate regions of operation. From the top of my head: Stack two NMOS transistors on top of each other, bias the bottom one in triode region, the upper one in active region. As the drain of the bottom transistor will follow changes made at the gate of the upper one, by:
[image]

You will get a multiplication of Vgs (bottom) and Vgs (top, as it leads to changes in Vds bottom)

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: The questioner I believe wants an amplifier even though multiplier was mentioned.

Comment: Ok, now I get it... Thanks for clearing up the misunderstanding, Andy. As for my answer: I provided this as a starting point for the implementation of a multiplying circuit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use darlington transistor to amplify the current.Darlington transistor give good output than common collector circuit.

Comment: You don't really need a darlington to multiply the current by 4. Any decent transistor would do that.

Comment: But i think stability in circuit is achieve through darling-ton transistor

Answer (score 0):

Pass 300ma through a transistor with its collector base connected. Use this collectors base voltage to bias 4 similar transistors in parallel as in current mirror configuration to obtain 4 x 300  = 1200ma.

Answer (score 0):

Use DC to dc step down, but the output
voltage must have lower than input voltage according output load.

Comment: Can you expand this answer?